# How can I specify nested for-loops in R which will repeat the same operation for multiple blocks of rows

Tags: r, for-loop

I am a beginner with R-loops and am somehow stuck with a probably very easy question:
I have a matrix with (for example) 3 blocks of trial sequences (1 block per participant, each block consists of 10 rows, all 10 rows of each block are marked with the same number in the variable "block", so 1-3). Now I want to count trial repetitions seperately for each block and I just don´t know how to do this with the loop-command.

For the following (example) matrix...

```
trial_matrix <- matrix(NA, nrow = 30, ncol = 4)
colnames(trial_matrix) <- c( "block","trial","trial type","repetition_count")
#blocks
trial_matrix[1:10,1] <- 1
trial_matrix[11:20,1] <- 2
trial_matrix[21:30,1] <- 3
#trial numbers for each block
trial_matrix[1:10,2] <- c(1:10)
trial_matrix[11:20,2] <- c(1:10)
trial_matrix[21:30,2] <- c(1:10)
#trial types
num <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1)
for (i in 1:30) {
  trial_matrix[i,3]<-sample(0:1,1)
  }
```

I tried the following code:

```
for(j in 1:3) { #for all 100 blocks
  count <- 0
  for(i in 1:10) { #for all rows of this specific block
    if(i>1) {
      count<-ifelse(trial_matrix[i,3]==trial_matrix[i-1,3],count +1,0) #repetitions are counted
      trial_matrix[i,"repetition_count"] <- count
    } else {
      trial_matrix[i,"repetition_count"]<-1
    }
  }
}
```

If I run the code, the repetitions are counted only in the first block. I know that I probably have to include "j" somewhere in the loop, but I don´t know how.

Comment: Can you show a small reproducible example with expected output

Comment: I think the issue is with `ifelse` as it takes vector but you are doing an element wise operation. Try with `if(tiral_matrix[i, 6] == trial_matrix[i-1, 6]) count = count + 1 else 0`. Also, I will caution that using for loops can be very slow for large matrix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could do this easily with `rle` from `base R`.  Do a grouping by 'block' for the 'trial type' column in `tapply`, apply the `rle`, get the  count index by `rep`licating the sequence of 'values' by the 'lengths' of `rle` output

```
trial_matrix[, "repetition_count"] <- unlist(tapply(
     trial_matrix[, "trial type"], trial_matrix[, "block"],
    FUN = function(x) with(rle(x), rep(seq_along(values), lengths))))
```

-output

```
trial_matrix
      block trial trial type repetition_count
 [1,]     1     1          0                1
 [2,]     1     2          1                2
 [3,]     1     3          0                3
 [4,]     1     4          0                3
 [5,]     1     5          1                4
 [6,]     1     6          0                5
 [7,]     1     7          1                6
 [8,]     1     8          1                6
 [9,]     1     9          0                7
[10,]     1    10          1                8
[11,]     2     1          0                1
[12,]     2     2          0                1
[13,]     2     3          1                2
[14,]     2     4          0                3
[15,]     2     5          0                3
[16,]     2     6          1                4
[17,]     2     7          0                5
[18,]     2     8          1                6
[19,]     2     9          1                6
[20,]     2    10          1                6
[21,]     3     1          1                1
[22,]     3     2          0                2
[23,]     3     3          0                2
[24,]     3     4          0                2
[25,]     3     5          0                2
[26,]     3     6          0                2
[27,]     3     7          1                3
[28,]     3     8          1                3
[29,]     3     9          1                3
[30,]     3    10          1                3
```

---

The same approach can be done using a `for` loop by incrementing the `count`

```
trial_matrix <- cbind(trial_matrix,  repetition_count2 = NA_integer_)
un1 <- unique(trial_matrix[, "block"])
for(j in un1) { 
  count <- 1
  tmp <- trial_matrix[trial_matrix[, "block"] == j, ]
  for(i in  seq_len(nrow(tmp))) {
   if(i == 1) {
    tmp[i,"repetition_count2"] <- count
      } else {
            if(tmp[i,3]!= tmp[i-1, 3]) {
              count <- count + 1  
             }
          tmp[i,"repetition_count2"] <- count
      
        } 
     }
  trial_matrix[trial_matrix[, "block"] == j, ] <- tmp
 }
```

-output

```
trial_matrix
      block trial trial type repetition_count repetition_count2
 [1,]     1     1          0                1                 1
 [2,]     1     2          1                2                 2
 [3,]     1     3          0                3                 3
 [4,]     1     4          0                3                 3
 [5,]     1     5          1                4                 4
 [6,]     1     6          0                5                 5
 [7,]     1     7          1                6                 6
 [8,]     1     8          1                6                 6
 [9,]     1     9          0                7                 7
[10,]     1    10          1                8                 8
[11,]     2     1          0                1                 1
[12,]     2     2          0                1                 1
[13,]     2     3          1                2                 2
[14,]     2     4          0                3                 3
[15,]     2     5          0                3                 3
[16,]     2     6          1                4                 4
[17,]     2     7          0                5                 5
[18,]     2     8          1                6                 6
[19,]     2     9          1                6                 6
[20,]     2    10          1                6                 6
[21,]     3     1          1                1                 1
[22,]     3     2          0                2                 2
[23,]     3     3          0                2                 2
[24,]     3     4          0                2                 2
[25,]     3     5          0                2                 2
[26,]     3     6          0                2                 2
[27,]     3     7          1                3                 3
[28,]     3     8          1                3                 3
[29,]     3     9          1                3                 3
[30,]     3    10          1                3                 3
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, @akrun. However, as j ranges from 1:100, unfortunately this does not work, as I don´t have 100 columns. The block-number is just specified in one column and I want to repeat the command for every 10 rows again.
Also thanks for the very helpful tip, I will try your recommended function!

Comment: @rbeginner can you update your post with a small example for testing.  This code was created based on some assumptions

Comment: yes, I have updated the code and added code for an example matrix with 3 blocks (in practice, I need more, but this fits to illustrate my problem.

Comment: @rbeginner do you need `tapply(trial_matrix[, "trial type"], trial_matrix[, "block"], FUN = rle)`

Comment: @rbeginner can yu check the output I posted

Comment: @rbeginner i updated with for loop as well.  please check in case you are interested

Comment: yes, your code helped me to do it! I just had to change some parts in the code, as the repetitions were not counted the way I needed it, but now it works. Thank you!